# AE: Not Assigned, Under Review -> AE: Not Assigned, Submitted

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, ieee

I submitted a paper to an IEEE journal two months ago. The status changed to: "AE: Not Assigned, Under Review" after about 4 weeks and now recently it changed to "AE: Not Assigned, Submitted" what does that mean? Have no reviewers been found in the last two months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Associate Editor (AE) has not yet been assigned to your article. Previously, it was under review by an internal administrative team. That team has now completed its work, hence the reversion to "submitted" status. Once an associate editor has been assigned, either the paper will go out for peer review or a desk-editorial decision will be made. As always with journal submissions, be patient. Be very very patient. It's only been a couple of months.

You might like to have a look at [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like? How should I interpret a particular submission status?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a)